# Get new object from viewport mesh

Tags: python

I want to get a new object from the mesh displayed in the viewport, with all it's modifiers, without having to copy and apply the modifier stack.

I believe this is how to do it, but it keeps crashing Blender:

```
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eval_obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].evaluated_get(dg)
bpy.data.collections['Defaults'].objects.link(eval_obj)
eval_obj.modifiers.clear()
```

Is this the best way to do this?

My goal is to have a copy of all visible objects with all their modifiers applied (exactly like `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')`) but simply running that takes a long time on many objects with many modifiers.
I'm hoping that I can get a copy of what is being displayed in the viewport as a new mesh object, without having to apply all the modifiers.